# How to restore a system?

Tags: partition, backup, debian

I have a disk image from Acronis True Image 2011. My original disk, of 40 GBs, had 2 partitions, 1 for FS and 1 for swap, but it started to fail.

I've tried to make a backup, which finished with some read errors. Then, I've tried to restore it in a 160 GB disk, selecting the 2 partitions, and MBR and track 0. The thing is that it is not booting, I only  see a `_` in the screen and nothing happens.

The question is if it is possible to re-install Debian, and then copy ALL the `/*` files, to get my programs and data back, or is more difficult than that.

Comment: Hm, are you using Debian?

Comment: Yes, debian 7, without graphic interface, its just web server

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the programs. Reinstalling all your old programs won't take long. Just try to get your data back from the disk image from Acronis True Image 2011, otherwise it would be like [Sisyphus and the rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus).